# What does this PowerShell snippet mean (syntax parsing help!)

Tags: powershell

I have the following snippet of PowerShell script in my profile:

```
. (join-path (split-path (& { $myInvocation.ScriptName })) "export-errors.ps1")
```

Now, I understand that this causes the script `export-errors.ps1` that exists in the same directory as my profile script to be executed. My question is, why?

I don't understand why the `& { xxx }` construct is different that just `xxx` in this case. I've attempted to use this similar construct:

```
$lame = join-path (split-path $myinvocation.mycommand.definition) "_lame\lame.exe"
```

This doesn't work, however. I get errors about providers not existing, and I don't really understand why.

Why does the first construct work, and the second one doesn't?

**UPDATE**

It's become clear to me that I was chasing the wrong bug. Indeed, both of the constructs work, under certain conditions. The condition under which I was running the second construct, however, is one under which NEITHER works. I'll post a separate question on that.

Keith is almost certainly correct when he says the first construct is an attempt to work around certain oddities. It was a copy-paste thing from a LONG time ago.

Comment: The 'lame' command works for me. `$lame` is a result string like `C:\TEMP\_101119_163554\_lame\lame.exe`. To execute it as command use . or & operator: `. $lame`.

Comment: BTW, this code should be invoked in a script otherwise it does not work as "expected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is probably over the top for dot sourcing in your profile.  The following should be sufficient in the context of your profile.ps1 script:

```
. (join-path (split-path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) export-errors.ps1)
```

Of course if you're dot sourcing more than one file you might want to go this route:

```
$ScriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $ScriptPath -Parent
. $ScriptDir\lib.ps1
```

I believe your original approach attempts to work around a problem I describe in [this blog post](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!7226.entry).